# Deduplicate Time Series Data When Multiple Redundant Sources Exists (Python or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, duplicates, time-series

Assume we have 2 systems (imagine IoT sensors) observing the same data source for redundancy, generating 2 time series data streams `A` and `B`. In the example below, `A` and `B` happens to be shifted by 1 second apart during these 5 seconds shown here, simulating latency. `A` is also missing the value `3` expected at time=4, which is found in `B` at time=3.

**Question:** In `grouped`, both  `A` and `B` have been combined together and were grouped by `time`. How can we then deduplicate the combined data stream `grouped`, so that we obtain the deduplicate time series `desired`?

*Notes:*

<sup>1</sup>If a duplicate data point exists in both `A` and `B`, we will keep the one that occurs earlier in time, and discard the newer duplicate.

<sup>2</sup>The deduplicated result does not require 100% accuracy. We just need a reasonable strategy to resolve uncertain scenarios during deduplication.

**Illustration of the 2 time-series `A` and `B`, and the desired deduplicated data `desired`**

```
// time(s)  A   B       desired
// ---------------------------

// 5        2      

// 4            2       2

// 3        1   3       3 

// 2        2   1       1

// 1        1   2       2

// 0            1       1
```

**Existing Code (Javascript)**

Feel free to use Javascript, Python, pseudo-code or similar languages. Javascript is highly preferred, libraries like Lodash/Pandas can be used.

```
// 2 data streams
const A = [
    {time: 5, score: 2},
    {time: 3, score: 1},
    {time: 2, score: 2},
    {time: 1, score: 1}
];

const B = [
    {time: 4, score: 2},
    {time: 3, score: 3},
    {time: 2, score: 1},
    {time: 1, score: 2},
    {time: 0, score: 1}
];

// After grouping both A and B by `time`, we get `grouped`
// Skipping the implementation here for simplicity
let grouped = [
    {time: 5, score: [2]},
    {time: 4, score: [2]},
    {time: 3, score: [1, 3]},
    {time: 2, score: [2, 1]},
    {time: 1, score: [1, 2]},
    {time: 0, score: [1]},
];
```

**Desired Result**

```
[
    {time: 4, score: [2]},
    {time: 3, score: [3]},
    {time: 2, score: [1]},
    {time: 1, score: [2]},
    {time: 0, score: [1]}, 
]
```

Comment: It's unclear how to decide that the `A` value at time 3 should be output before the `B` value at time 3...

Comment: @Nick If it is OK to have some errors in the deduplicated result, is it then reasonable to give preference to the data from one of the systems (like `A`) when such uncertainty arises during dedupe? If so, will this allow the scenario you described to be resolved?

Comment: I'd probably be inclined to shift the `A` values to take account of the latency (presumably it is fixed - or close enough to allow the shift to be computed?) and then take A if B is missing or the same as A, B if A is missing and either A or B (consistently) if both are present but different...